# ssh proxying tool

Tags: ssh, proxy

Do you know any open source solution for proxying ssh connections transparently(MITM). My aim is to 
- while allowing forward shh connections, block ssh reverse tunnels
- block http proxy over ssh (to force ssh just for commands not as a pipe to internet)
- whitelist or blacklist some some commands
thru this proxy.

Do you know any solution that converges my aims?

Comment: Users can misuse their right to make ssh command connections for tunneling. This is constructive while my question is not!

Answer (score 1):

Its not open source, but Palo Alto devices will do some of what youre describing. See references below , though whatever you use will either require clients to use a key from the man in the middle device to decrypt the traffic or youll end up with clients having errors about encryption.

[For Example](http://www.paloaltonetworks.com/products/features/decryption.html),  [Further details here](http://www.paloaltonetworks.com/literature/techbriefs/App_ID_tech.pdf),   and  [Here](http://www.what2code.net/?p=100)